# Bootstrapping for groups of unequal size

Tags: sampling, bootstrap, group-differences

I am making a bootstrapping function comparing two groups. One group is about twice as large as the other. Should I sample the dataset completely at random or does my sampling method need to somehow take into account the uneven group sizes? The sampling scheme for the study itself was completely at random (observational study and one condition was much more prevalent than the other).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to use the bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have samples `x1` and `x2` of sizes $n_1 = 500, n_2 = 1000$ from two populations and you want a 95% CI for the difference $\delta=\mu_1 -\mu_2$ of the two sample means.
If you have no detailed information about the shapes of the population distributions, then you could make a 95% nonparametric bootstrap confidence interval for $\delta.$

*Data summaries (using R):*

```
summary(x1); length(x1); sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  30.03   32.39   34.80   34.90   37.13   39.97 
[1] 500         # sample size
[1] 2.909158    # sample SD
summary(x2); length(x2); sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  21.17   29.88   32.10   32.08   34.20   42.47 
[1] 1000
[1] 3.068106

boxplot(x1, x2, horizontal=T, names=T, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

```
par(mfrow= c(1,2))
 qqnorm(x1, col="skyblue2"); qqline(x1, lwd=2)
 qqnorm(x2, col="skyblue2"); qqline(x2, lwd=2)
par(mfrow= c(1,1))
```

[image]

From these graphs, it seems clear that the first sample (lower boxplot, normal quantile plot in left panel) is not from a normal population and that
the second sample is consistent with sampling from some normal population.
[Normal samples with a thousand observations typically show a few near outliers in both tails.] Sample sizes are large enough that Shapiro-Wilk tests confirm what we see
in the plots.

```
shapiro.test(x1)$p.val
[1] 3.113721e-11
shapiro.test(x2)$p.val
[1] 0.5282596
```

Even with these large sample sizes, I would not be eager to take as definitive  the CI $(2.50,3.14)$ provided
by the Welch 2-sample t test procedure (in R).

```
t.test(x1,x2)$conf.int
[1] 2.504009 3.140931
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

*95% Nonparametric Bootstrap CI.* Then I could do repeated re-samples with replacement from `x1` (size $n_1)$ and `x2` (size $n_2).$  For simplicity and brevity here, I choose a simple quantile 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI for $\delta$ shown below, which gives CI $(2.50, 3.13).$ [Notice that this CI is similar to the t CI and that neither comes anywhere near including $0.]$

```
set.seed(514)
d.re = replicate(3000,  mean(sample(x1, 500, rep=T)) - 
                  mean(sample(x2, 1000, rep=T)))
quantile(d.re, c(.025, .975))
    2.5%    97.5% 
2.504595 3.132644
```

By contrast, let's look at tests of $H_0: \delta = 0$ against $H_a: \delta \ne 0.$.
A possibly inappropriate pooled 2-sample t test rejects $H_0$ with a very large t statistic `t.obs`:

```
x = c(x1, x2);  g = c(rep(1,500), rep(2,1000))
t.obs = t.test(x ~ g, var.eq=T)$stat;  t.obs
       t 
17.08538
```

Although I have misgivings about the distribution of the pooled t statistic, I
am willing to use this statistic as a 'metric' for judging whether the two population variances are equal.

A simple simulated permutation test, based on thismetric, repeatedly scrambles the $n_1+n-1$ observations
at random with 500 in the first group and 1000 in the second. For each permutation of the data a fresh pooled t statistic (element of `t.prm`) is computed. The P-value of the permutation
test is the proportion of values in `t.prm` with absolute values larger than
the absolute value of `t.obs`. The permutation rejects with a P-value $0.$

```
set.seed(521)
t.prm = replicate(10^5, t.test(x~sample(g), var.eq=T)$stat)
mean(abs(t.prm) >= abs(t.obs))
[1] 0

hist(t.prm, prob=T, xlim=c(-20,20), col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 abline(v = c(-t.obs, t.obs), col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

*Notes:* (1) It is important to understand that while a bootstrap and a permutation test
both use re-sampling of the data, the methods of re-sampling are quite different.

(2) The following R code was used to sample the fictitious data used in the examples above:

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = round(runif(500, 30,40), 2)
x2 = round(rnorm(1000, 32, 3), 2)
```

Comment: Should the sample sizes be n_1 = 500 and n_2 = 1000 at the very beginning of the answer? In any case, thanks for an excellent explanation.

Comment: Fixed the typos, thanks.